# How to print a poster (diagram >1 page) in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: macos, printing, intellij-idea

I know that it is possible to print a poster (multiple-page diagram) (in particular, a persistence diagram) in IntelliJ IDEA, but I have apparently forgotten how. When I bring up the "Print Graph" dialog, I can modify the "Poster Rows" and "Poster Columns" values, but they do not appear to have any effect. (If it matters, the next time I bring up the dialog, they are invariably set back to the values "1" and "1.")

OS-X, if it makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

This is a yFiles library bug. Today I committed a workaround to solve it.

Comment: Will that be included in an upcoming point-release, or is there a URL that shows the work-around?